# Need Google Forms to validate only responses that are correctly formatted

Tags: regex, google-forms

I need students to input their student IDs, and it will be hard to collate if they make mistakes. I would love to make sure input adheres to possible ID numbers, which is three numerals followed by one uppercase letter followed by three numerals. For example, 221F032 would be validated, but not s221F032, or 221f032. To complicate things, there is a rare exception: returning students' IDs are two uppercase letters followed by five numerals. I need to allow this combination, too.

Can I do this, and, if so, how? Also, if there is an expression that would do this, when creating the form do I select "Regular expression" and "Matches"? (Yes, I am new to regular expressions. I am but a benighted cultural anthropologist who studies comics.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form, select "Regular expression" and enter this:

```
^(\d{3}[A-Z]\d{3}|[A-Z]{2}\d{5})$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at beginning
- `(` - group start (start of logical OR)
- `\d{3}[A-Z]\d{3}` - expect 3 digits, one uppercase letter, and 3 digits
- `|` - logical OR
- `[A-Z]{2}\d{5}` - expect two uppercase letter, and 5 digits
- `)` - group end
- `$` - anchor at end